# GIT on 'mountain lion' will not execute commands

Tags: path, git, macintosh

Macbookpro Mountion Lion 10.8.5

I cannot get GIT to execute commands. 
I have been researching and trouble shooting for 2 days.
Some suggestions I have tried are listed at the end.
Below will just be the commands and console output which may clearly identify the issue to people familiar with this issue.

I am following a course online.
I installed GIT from git-scm.com

```
$  which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/
$ git --version
git version 2.0.1
$ git init new_repository
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
$
```

Suggestions and Points I took from researching.

A suggestion is that the version of GIT is a mismatch to my Mac
I am trying to uninstall this way.
In the GIT.pkg there is an uninstall.sh file

```
$ sudo sh uninstall.sh
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
Password:
sh: uninstall.sh: No such file or directory
```

Looks like the uninstall.sh was not copied when I installed GIT

I tried these commands

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git etc/paths.d/git rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
permission denied
```

A suggestion to add/modify the path in my .bash_profile with these different options and this did not change anything:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
```

or

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

How can I uninstall GIT ?

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you want to uninstall git or fix the errors you're getting?

Comment: Thanks. I did uninstall GIT.  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/bin/git
I did a 'which git' and it returned empty. Then I reinstalled a different version that was not a mismatch to my Mac and I am running fine.

Comment: Oh, OK. In that case could you either post an answer or delete this since it's not likely to ever be answered otherwise?

Comment: @terdon. Maybe I should post this separately.  When I was troubleshooting the git install, I did a few things.  I think that I modified my default path.  Echo $path returns /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin I hope I typed that correctly.  That seems wrong. Why would git be included in my top level path.  Can you explain ?